# How can I catch the Print option being selected in the File menu/tab in Word 2016 (backstage view)?

Tags: vba, printing, ms-word

The following code opens the screen I want to detect being opened:

```
Sub Test()
  Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("PrintPreviewAndPrint")
End Sub
```

It does not seem to activate a CommandBarButton object I can create an event handler for. Any thoughts on how to do this without having to change the structure of the File Tab because this is only relevant for one document. The goal is to be able to set duplex printing before the document is printed while the standard File->Print option can still be used.

Answer (score 2):

You can go old school. Before there were events to trap it was common to intercept commands simply by creating a routine with the same name.

For example:

```
Public Sub PrintPreviewAndPrint()
   MsgBox "Hello!"
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you can trap the `DocumentBeforePrint` event, though this will only fire after the dialog has been executed.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, there is no macro "PrintPreviewAndPrint" that can be captured this way due to how the Backstage view works. And the DocumentBeforePrint event is indeed triggered too late.

Comment: See also:https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/InterceptSavePrint.htm and https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/AppClassEvents.htm.

Comment: @A.Boersma - " there is no macro "PrintPreviewAndPrint" that can be captured this way" - no there isn't. You have to write it, as I explained in my answer. And no, you can't display the Backstage view, but you can do everything that you say you want to do in your question without it.

Comment: @A.Boersma - I should point out that the above method has the advantage of trapping the Ctrl+P keyboard shortcut, and the button in the Quick Access Toolbar. If you only use the slow method of accessing Print then you're only option would be to hack the Backstage view, which seems rather over the top for  single document.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to repurpose backstage UI controls, but you can create your own UI instead. So, a better solution would be to consider hiding the built-in UI and rebuilding it fully with custom commands. The [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691833(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) article explains the basics of building a custom backstage UI.

The [Application.DocumentBeforePrint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.documentbeforeprint) event allows canceling the default action, so you can programmatically print the document in the way you want by using the [PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.printout) method.

```
Public WithEvents appWord as Word.Application 
 
Private Sub appWord_DocumentBeforePrint _ 
 (ByVal Doc As Document, _ 
 Cancel As Boolean) 
 
 Dim intResponse As Integer 
 
 intResponse = MsgBox("Have you checked the " _ 
 & "printer for letterhead?", _ 
 vbYesNo) 
 
 If intResponse = vbNo Then Cancel = True 
End Sub
```